# Losing network connectivity to some internet services

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I keep losing network connectivity to some internet services but not all. Skype for instance, works fine(I had a VoIP chat going during). But seemingly out of the blue, i loose everything else it seems. I try to ping google, with an unknown host error after a long wait. Restarting my Modem/Router fixes the problem for a while, but then after about 30-60 min the problem is back. I will be contacting my ISP but was wondering if anyone here might have an idea to what the problem might be.

All clients lose the same services, so I'm guessing its not a client problem.
Clients include two iOS devices, a PS3 and two Mac OS X Yosemite clients.

As well, I'm running a MineCraft Server(TCP protocol) which always seems to be connected.

I have set my primary DNS server to OpenDNS 208.67.220.220. Waiting to see if that helped(here's hoping)

Comment: I suggest you to check your performance using Google dns 8.8.8.8  and 8.8.4.4

Comment: How are you sure that skype is still functioning?  Are you able to chat/call on it during this "outage"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many reasons this could happen.
In my case, it seemed to be the DNS settings on the router.
It was set to use 10.0.0.1(Address of the router) as both the primary and secondary DNS. Changed the primary DNS server to google's **8.8.8.8**, and it seems to work(The situation explained has not happened since)

If that does not work for someone else particular situation, the other answer may help.

Comment: Have you considered letting the router get its DNS setting automatically from your ISP?

Answer (score 5):

First you need to find out whether it's your ISP's or your PC's problem. If other computer/OS on your network has same problem, then it's either your modem/router or ISP. If other OS plays well, then I guess the problem is on your PC's end.

It could be anything. ISP, improper router setup, malware/virus on your PC, ... How long as this been going on? When did you first notice? What OS do you use? Does it also happen with different OS's? How strong is your wifi password? Is anyone else using it and eating your connection?

Answer (score 0):

I too would check DNS first.  However, if that doesn't help, I have seen this happen many times before due to a corrupted winsock catalog.  This typically happens after removing viruses or malware which messes with the settings.

To fix, open a command prompt as administrator, and run these commands

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log hit
```

then restart your computer.